# Ordered list item loses marker on Safari

Tags: html, safari, html-lists

I have an ordered list. Each item contains a `details` element. After I expand or collapse the details, the list marker disappears in **Safari**. I am not using JavaScript, just native `summary` and `details` tags.

Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/socemazuwi/

Raw JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/socemazuwi/1/edit

Comment: This appears to be a bug in Safari. Have you checked https://bugs.webkit.org?